# splunk rex command to search exception and count the error codes

Tags: splunk, rex

I have raw data which looks something like this :

```
[6/24/22 6:45:20:277 IST] 000005d4 Output     O abcd-ddd-dd.ppp1.ttttttt.net sys      2022-06-24T06:45:20,277 WARN [Server.BatchProcess] Limoc Input : Exception occurred: 100 COMPRESS 'success' EEEE08EE.ERROR-TEXT(1) null
[6/24/22 6:45:20:277 IST] 000005d4 Output     O abcd-ddd-dd.ppp1.ttttttt.net sys      2022-06-24T06:45:20,277 WARN [Server.BatchProcess] Limoc Input : Exception occurred: 101 COMPRESS 'success' EEEE08EE.ERROR-TEXT(2) null
```

I need help with the rex command which can filter all the messages with "`Limoc Input : Exception occurred: 100`" "`Limoc Input : Exception occurred: 101`" and similar ones like this and take a count of  them and also print the message following it "`COMPRESS 'success' EEEE08EE.ERROR-TEXT(1) null`". For example:

```
100 COMPRESS 'success' EEEE08EE.ERROR-TEXT(1) null 2
101 COMPRESS 'success' EEEE08EE.ERROR-TEXT(2) null 3
```

Comment: You could use the LIke function in Eval https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.0/SearchReference/ConditionalFunctions#like.28TEXT.2C_PATTERN.29

the like function would look like: like(_raw,"%Limoc Input : Exception occurred: 101%")

Comment: The `rex` command neither filters nor counts.  It extracts fields.  Use the `regex` command to filter events based on whether they match or fail to match a regular expression.  Of course, events that are filtered cannot be counted because they're no longer in the results.

Answer (score 0):

See if this run-anywhere search gets you going in the right direction.

````
| makeresults
| eval data="[6/24/22 6:45:20:277 IST] 000005d4 Output O abcd-ddd-dd.ppp1.ttttttt.net sys 2022-06-24T06:45:20,277 WARN [Server.BatchProcess] Limoc Input : Exception occurred: 100 COMPRESS 'success' EEEE08EE.ERROR-TEXT(1) null
[6/24/22 6:45:20:277 IST] 000005d4 Output O abcd-ddd-dd.ppp1.ttttttt.net sys 2022-06-24T06:45:20,277 WARN [Server.BatchProcess] Limoc Input : Exception occurred: 101 COMPRESS 'success' EEEE08EE.ERROR-TEXT(2) null"
| eval data=split(data,"
")
| mvexpand data
| eval _raw=data
| fields - data
```Everything above just sets up test data.  Omit IRL```
```Extract the exception number and text which follows```
| rex "Limoc Input : Exception occurred: (?<Exception>10[01]) (?<DisplayText>.*)"
```Count the occurrences.  Copy the text.```
| stats values(DisplayText) as DisplayText, count by Exception
```Display the results```
| table DisplayText count
````

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the help, I was able to count and search using searchmatch

Answer (score 0):

Start with a base search looking for your keying text:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp "Limoc Input : Exception occurred"
```

Based on [your sample data](https://regex101.com/r/b3IL0u/1), this [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex) will pull what you're looking for into a new field `msg`:

```
| rex field=_raw ":\s+(?<msg>\d+\s+\w+.+)"
```

You can then [`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats) it into a table:

```
| stats count by msg
```

Comment: Hi All , as per Daniel comment, I am able to count the errors with the code by using the below: eval error=case(_raw LIKE "%Limoc Input : Exception occurred: 100%", "100 COMPRESS 'success' EEEE08EE.ERROR-TEXT(1)", _raw LIKE "%Limoc Input : Exception occurred: 101%", "101 COMPRESS 'success' EEEE08EE.ERROR-TEXT(2)",_raw LIKE "%", "Others") | stats count by error .
This gives me result like this:
100 COMPRESS 'success' EEEE08EE.ERROR-TEXT(1)  4
Others                                                                    2000

Comment: But I also want to display the result value of the one which gives 0.
100 COMPRESS 'success' EEEE08EE.ERROR-TEXT(1)   4
100 COMPRESS 'success' EEEE08EE.ERROR-TEXT(2)   0

Comment: @Diksha - you can't "count" what isn't there. There won't be any results with a 0, you'll only see what's found :)